# Python Titanic dataset:issue with loop that creates new future

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to create new future:if someone is alone on Titanic(Sibsp and parch has to be 0)
Here is my code:

```
df_train["Is_alone1"] = df_train["SibSp"].map(lambda x:1 if x == 0 else 0)
df_train["Is_alone2"] = df_train["Parch"].map(lambda x:1 if x == 0 else 0)
Is_alone=[]
def is_alone():
    for x, y in list(df_train["Is_alone1"]),list(df_train["Is_alone2"]):
        if x == 1 and y == 1:
            Is_alone.append(int(1))
        else:
            Is_alone.append(int(0))
```

But Is_alone is still empty. How to correct this?
I'm using python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without looping, just comparing the values of the columns.

```
is_alone = (df_train["SibSp"] == 0) & (df_train["Parch"] == 0)
df_train["Is_alone"] = is_alone.astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks! But just for learning purposes, do you maybe know what is wrong with my loop?

Comment: @econ Ah, yes, of course, you're right. Well, your loop doesn't look wrong really, I mean it might be a bit slower but the result should be the same. Are you actually calling the function `is_alone()` that you have defined? Otherwise the code within it will never run.

Comment: `df_train["Is_alone"] = df_train["SibSp"].astype(int)` is correct?

Comment: I think you want `df_train["Is_alone"] = is_alone.astype(int)`

Comment: @jezrael Ah yes, thank you, of course that's the right one!